# How to reference server inbox instead of offline inbox?

Tags: vba, server, outlook, inbox

I want to iterate through my entire Outlook inbox, including messages stored on the MS Exchange Server.  However, when I reference my Outlook inbox via:

```
NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

It only returns the items in my offline inbox.  Does anybody know how to return the entire server archive?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something to your ThisOutlookSession (vba) before you are able to perform what you would like to do.

Please refer to the following website. There is a lot explained about connecting to shared folders (exchange) and calendars.

https://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

Comment: I have tried that macro but I do not think it will be able to help.  The code below only works for index "1", and it returns my personal e-mail address.  Therefore the only folder that that function can return to me is the parent folder for my Inbox, Sent Items, Deleted Items, etc. (which is equivalent to my profile or account maybe?)

Comment: MsgBox Session.Folders.Item( [Index as Integer] ) only accepts an Index of 1, and returns my e-mail address.  MsgBox Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders("Inbox") returns my Inbox.

Comment: Using "GetSharedDefaultFolder" instead of "GetDefaultFolder" does not work either, because the folders returned by both methods each return the same Folder.Items.Count, which is the number of MailItems in my offline Inbox, but not my Exchange Inbox

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the folder in the online mode. You can either

1. Turn cached mode off (not ideal from the performance point of course)
2. Reopen the folder in the online mode using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) using `IMAPISession::OpenEntry` and the `MAPI_NO_CACHE` (`0x0200`) flag.
3. Reopen the folder using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - any language) - it exposes (2) above:

   ```
   MAPI_NO_CACHE = &H200 
   MAPI_BEST_ACCESS &H10
   set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
   Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
   set vFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(YourOOMFolder.EntryID, , MAPI_NO_CACHE + MAPI_BEST_ACCESS)
   MsgBox vFolder.Items.Count
   ```